# How can I upload images with PHP using Prestashop?

Tags: php, image, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm trying to do an automatic upload of products using a SOAP API with Prestashop PHP coding.

The product seems to be upload correctly, but the images are not rendering correctly in the frontoffice (the backoffice does). I've tried several pieces of code I found on the internet but none satisfied what I needed.

I have a class named `Jubaconfig.php` where I execute the code to import the products. Each product is created by the following way:

```
$product = new Product();
                $product->name[1] = $productInfo->name;
                $product->reference = $productInfo->product_id;
                $product->description[1] = $productInfo->description;
                $product->description_short[1] = $productInfo->short_description;
                $product->active = 1;
                $product->condition = "new";
                $product->id_tax_rules_group = 1;
                $product->id_manufacturer = 3;
                $product->id_category_default = 49;
                $product->add();
                $product->save();

                $product->addToCategories(array(49));
                StockAvailable::setQuantity((int)$product->id, 0, $product->quantity);
                // Añadimos la imagen al producto

                $cover = true;
                $image_url = ($productInfo->additional_attributes[0]->value);

                var_dump($image_url);
                echo "<br>";

                $image = new Image();
                $image->id_product = $product->id;
                $image->position = Image::getHighestPosition($product->id) + 1;
                $image->cover = $cover;
                if (($image->validateFields(false, true)) === true &&
                    ($image->validateFieldsLang(false, true)) === true && $image->add())
                {
                    $image->associateTo($product->id_shop_default);
                    if (!Jubaconfig::copyImg($product->id, $image->id, $image_url, 'products', false))
                    {
                        $image->delete();
                    }
                }
```

The function `copyImg` is the following:

```
public function copyImg($id_entity, $id_image = null, $url = '', $entity = 'products', $regenerate = true)
    {
        $tmpfile = tempnam(_PS_TMP_IMG_DIR_, 'ps_import');
        $watermark_types = explode(',', Configuration::get('WATERMARK_TYPES'));

        switch ($entity) {
            default:
            case 'products':
                $image_obj = new Image($id_image);
                $path = $image_obj->getPathForCreation();
                break;
            case 'categories':
                $path = _PS_CAT_IMG_DIR_ . (int) $id_entity;
                break;
            case 'manufacturers':
                $path = _PS_MANU_IMG_DIR_ . (int) $id_entity;
                break;
            case 'suppliers':
                $path = _PS_SUPP_IMG_DIR_ . (int) $id_entity;
                break;
            case 'stores':
                $path = _PS_STORE_IMG_DIR_ . (int) $id_entity;
                break;
        }

        $url = urldecode(trim($url));
        $parced_url = parse_url($url);

        if (isset($parced_url['path'])) {
            $uri = ltrim($parced_url['path'], '/');
            $parts = explode('/', $uri);
            foreach ($parts as &$part) {
                $part = rawurlencode($part);
            }
            unset($part);
            $parced_url['path'] = '/' . implode('/', $parts);
        }

        if (isset($parced_url['query'])) {
            $query_parts = array();
            parse_str($parced_url['query'], $query_parts);
            $parced_url['query'] = http_build_query($query_parts);
        }

        if (!function_exists('http_build_url')) {
            require_once _PS_TOOL_DIR_ . 'http_build_url/http_build_url.php';
        }

        $url = http_build_url('', $parced_url);

        $orig_tmpfile = $tmpfile;

        if (Tools::copy($url, $tmpfile)) {
            // Evaluate the memory required to resize the image: if it's too much, you can't resize it.
            if (!ImageManager::checkImageMemoryLimit($tmpfile)) {
                @unlink($tmpfile);

                return false;
            }

            $tgt_width = $tgt_height = 0;
            $src_width = $src_height = 0;
            $error = 0;
            ImageManager::resize($tmpfile, $path . '.jpg', null, null, 'jpg', false, $error, $tgt_width, $tgt_height, 5, $src_width, $src_height);
            $images_types = ImageType::getImagesTypes($entity, true);

            if ($regenerate) {
                $previous_path = null;
                $path_infos = array();
                $path_infos[] = array($tgt_width, $tgt_height, $path . '.jpg');
                foreach ($images_types as $image_type) {
                    $tmpfile = self::get_best_path($image_type['width'], $image_type['height'], $path_infos);

                    if (ImageManager::resize(
                        $tmpfile,
                        $path . '-' . stripslashes($image_type['name']) . '.jpg',
                        $image_type['width'],
                        $image_type['height'],
                        'jpg',
                        false,
                        $error,
                        $tgt_width,
                        $tgt_height,
                        5,
                        $src_width,
                        $src_height
                    )) {
                        // the last image should not be added in the candidate list if it's bigger than the original image
                        if ($tgt_width <= $src_width && $tgt_height <= $src_height) {
                            $path_infos[] = array($tgt_width, $tgt_height, $path . '-' . stripslashes($image_type['name']) . '.jpg');
                        }
                        if ($entity == 'products') {
                            if (is_file(_PS_TMP_IMG_DIR_ . 'product_mini_' . (int) $id_entity . '.jpg')) {
                                unlink(_PS_TMP_IMG_DIR_ . 'product_mini_' . (int) $id_entity . '.jpg');
                            }
                            if (is_file(_PS_TMP_IMG_DIR_ . 'product_mini_' . (int) $id_entity . '_' . (int) Context::getContext()->shop->id . '.jpg')) {
                                unlink(_PS_TMP_IMG_DIR_ . 'product_mini_' . (int) $id_entity . '_' . (int) Context::getContext()->shop->id . '.jpg');
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (in_array($image_type['id_image_type'], $watermark_types)) {
                        Hook::exec('actionWatermark', array('id_image' => $id_image, 'id_product' => $id_entity));
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            @unlink($orig_tmpfile);

            return false;
        }
        unlink($orig_tmpfile);

        return true;
    }
```

When I go to the Products section in the backoffice, the products are correctly uploaded, even the pictures. However, in the frontoffice, the products are still showing, but the images are not rendered because the image source is not the correct one.

Tip: If I edit a recently added product and save it, the image starts displaying in the frontoffice. But what I need is to display all the images I imported without having to save each product one by one.

Comment: Did you try to regenerate images after products uploading? I mean go to Improve->Design->Image Settings->Regenerate thumbnails and pick products images to regenerate

Comment: Yes, but I still not working. The thing is that my images in the frontoffice shows a question mark until I save them in the backoffice. I think it is related to the generation of paths in the directory /img/p, but I still don't know how to proceed

Comment: Try to save your $product after you add images. Put $product->save() to the end of your script. It may help

Comment: Still no effect. The thing is that the images are associated to the products correctly at the DB, but the picture at the frontoffice has a question mark until I save them manually at the backoffice

Comment: Did you check if the images exist in img/p/ path with used type?

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, disabling the Friendly URL option solved this. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is what I use in similar cases (the example is for product images but you get the idea).

```
**
     * Creates/updates product images
     * @param int    $id_product
     * @param string $img_name
     * @return bool
     */
    private function createImage($id_product, $img_name)
    {
        $url = Configuration::get('My_KEY') . "v1/images/" . $img_name . ".jpg";
        $shops = Shop::getShops(true, null, true);
        $image = new Image();
        $image->id_product = $id_product;
        $image->position = Image::getHighestPosition($id_product) + 1;
        $image->cover = true;
        if(($image->validateFields(false, true)) === true && ($image->validateFieldsLang(false, true)) === true
            && $image->add()) {
            $image->associateTo($shops);
            if(!AdminImportController::copyImg($id_product, $image->id, $url, 'products', true)) {
                file_put_contents($this->log, $this->date . " createImage error creating image" . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
                $image->delete();

            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Using the existing PS core controller (since 1.6+) seems the easiest way to me.